# Registry design

Tags: c++

I need to design a application registry S/W component using C++. Basically, this needs to support addition and deletion of key/values. Dynamic updates need to be supported (for example, when a new application get installed). 
Is there a design pattern which closely matches the given problem?
Though I have formulated a rough sketch of the APIs this component needs to support, it would be helpful to have a look at alternative (perhaps better) ways of design. 
If there are some typical problems associated with registry design (may be some thread issues which I might have overlooked), I want to make sure I have circumvented those.

Comment: Since you have designed something please share it to get SO opinion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a design pattern which closely matches the given problem?

You are probably looking at more than one: A [proxy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_pattern) for the entire registry, [iterator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterator_pattern) etc. comes to mind.

> If there are some typical problems associated with registry design

- You will probably need transactional semantics. Rollback too!
- Do you need to save snapshots from time to time? Then you will need an archiving module.
- Synchronization: Multiple writes to the registry need to be taken care of.